# OpenCL AMD APP Driver cannot detect GPU on Linux Server

Tags: opencl, amd-processor

I use AMD A8-3870 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics and Ubuntu 3.0.0-12-server.

I install the amd-driver 12-6 for x86_64.

However, when I run clinfo, I cannot detect the GPU device. Instead, it returns the CPU information.

Is it because I'm using APU or there is something wrong with the amd-driver and linux server?

Thank you~

Comment: As far as I know, AMD OpenCL implementation requires access to X server to use GPUs (not sure about APUs, but likely the same). Make sure your X server is running, is configured for using integrated GPU and (if you are connected via `ssh`) you have done all necessary steps [described on AMD's website](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/assets/App_Note-Running_AMD_APP_Apps_Remotely.pdf)

Comment: I think you are right. However, when I configure the X server, I found that there is no ati device listed in /dev folder. Do I need to set it up some how for this?

Comment: Check if `ati-config --lsa` finds your APU. If it does not, it's likely your driver was incorrectly installed. If it does, just let it configure Xorg automagically (`sudo aticonfig  --adapter=all --initial`), it usually helps.

Answer (score 0):

The AMD integrated GPU is materially disabled at startup as soon as a discrete GPU is plugged in. cf for example http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/153198